# How to get URL from an overlay if the webpage was shown in an overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

I have a search page. Now i wanted to open the search page when the user clicks on a certain link. Now i do some query search ,select some filter so as i proceed the new parametrs are added to the url.

For example when I do search for "club" query in google search I see the following url.

```
     http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=club&pbx=1&oq=club&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=257848l258668l2l259633l5l4l0l0l0l3l462l1655l3-1.3l4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=aeb16183bfd07c66&biw=1280&bih=628
```

Now i filter my search and select image filter from the left side options my url look like the following

```
    http://www.google.com/search?q=club&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=628&prmd=ivnsm&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=_4wwTsvfNdDQsgac0cz0Dw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBAQ_AUoAQ
```

Now i want to put my search page in an overlay. And then when the user is done with all search he can click "OK" button on bottom right of the overlay . So when the user clicks "OK" i want the URL which is generated when the search page normally opens up in tab window like the one shown above for google case.

Comment: Are you asking to put the URL into an iframe programatically?

Comment: I didn't mention anywhere about Iframe

Comment: I meant Overlay for eg http://jsfiddle.net/cmssites/FRDKq/16/

Comment: You want to display a google search page, in an overlay without using an iframe? That's not really possible, unless you use something like YQL. If you are, and you're injecting the html yourself after making an ajax request, I would think you would keep track of the url in the JS rather than in the browser url bar.

Comment: I am not using YQL. Okay so you mean that Inside the overlay I should put an iframe and then put the goole URL inside it. Look good point to me. But still how can i get the URL .Could you explain your line in a more better way :"I would think you would keep track of the url in the JS"

Comment: The example at http://jsfiddle.net/cmssites/FRDKq/16/ does use an iframe.

Comment: @Saurabh, if you're using an iframe, and the iframe is loading a url from another domain, you won't be able to because of cross domain security. You'll be able to access the src attribute on the iframe, but that won't be the updated url after someone does a google search. And trying to access the url will result in a Permission Denied

Answer (score -1):

An overlay (or a modal overlay in the example you've provided) for a separate site can be accomplished using JavaScript, css, and an iframe.

If you are interested in using an existing library, jQuery ui has a very nice overlay they call the dialog. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

If you don't want to use a library then you have to do something similar to the following code. Note: This code is very basic and doesn't provide many features available by using a library that handles overlays.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    //Define a class to create and control the overlay
    function overlay(width, height) {

        var container, iframe;

        this.setLocation = function(url) {
            iframe.setAttribute('src', url);
        }

        this.getLocation = function(url) {
            return iframe.getAttribute('src');
        }

        this.show = function() {
            container.style.display = 'block';
        }

        this.hide = function() {
            container.style.display = 'none';
        }

        function windowSize() {
            var winW = 630, winH = 460;
            if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
                winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
                winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
            }
            if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
                winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
                winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
            }
            if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
                winW = window.innerWidth;
                winH = window.innerHeight;
            }
            return [ winW, winH ];
        };

        (function() {
            //create the containing element
            container = document.createElement('div');
            container.style.position = 'fixed';
            container.style.top = '0px';
            container.style.left = '0px';
            container.style.right = '0px';
            container.style.bottom = '0px';
            container.style.zIndex = 1000;
            container.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)';

            //create the iframe
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
            iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
            iframe.style.width = width + 'px';
            iframe.style.height = height + 'px';
            iframe.style.left = ((windowSize()[0] - width) / 2) + 'px';
            iframe.style.top = ((windowSize()[1] - height) / 2) + 'px';

            container.appendChild(iframe);
            document.body.appendChild(container);
        })(this)

    }

    //create an overlay object, set it's location, and show it
    var win = new overlay(700, 400);
    win.setLocation('http://www.google.com/');
    win.show();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```